# Inserting HTML inside an HTML with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I wonder if there's a function that prints out the content of an HTML file, inside another HTML file?

Below's HTML #1;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Content
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML #2;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    %%[function]%%
</body>
</html>
```

I want the function inside HTML#2 to print out the p tag, which is in HTML#1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save HTML#1 as an content block and retrieve it via ContentBlockbyID

You can find more information about the function here:
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentblockbyid6/

Comment: Or you can use [ContentArea](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentarea3/) or [ContentAreaByName](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentareabyname4/) if you are using Classic Content emails.