# Adding AMPscript code to HTML

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am new at using AMPscript coding and I need to add some AMPscript code to an HTML email.  Where in the code do I place the AMPscript code.  Do I place it in the  of the HTML?  Or in the  portion of the HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161898/inserting-html-inside-an-html-with-ampscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very opened-ended question, but one small example would be:

```
%%[
   set @title = "This is the title of the html document"
   set @color = "#CCCCCC"
]%%

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>%%=v(@title)=%%</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="%%=v(@color)=%%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
     Text Content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The title and background color of that table will be what you specify in the variable declarations.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the training / guides here: https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/ampscript_101/

Answer (score 0):

Ampscript is independent of your HTML code, you can place the ampscript either inside or outside of your HTML code.